# print the array when it is exploded

Tags: php

In the below code i am getting the output

`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )`

but the expected output is

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

why  is it always executing the second if condition? although the first condition is also true. 
this is the code I have tried

```
    <?php 
$test_arr=array();
$temp_option_arr=array();
$option_arr=array();

$options_array_val = Array ( 0 => "animals:1", 1 => "animals:2", 2 => "animals:3", 3 => "birds:1", 4 => "birds:2" );

    foreach($options_array_val as $options_val)
    {
        $search_filter = explode(":", $options_val);
        print_r($search_filter);
        if(!in_array($search_filter[0],$option_arr))
        {
            array_push($temp_option_arr,$search_filter[1]);
            array_push($option_arr,$search_filter[0]);
            $temp_option_arr=array();

        }
        array_push($temp_option_arr,$search_filter[1]);
    }
    $test_arr[$search_filter[0]]=$temp_option_arr;
    $find_species = array();
    if(!empty($test_arr['animals']))
    {

        $find_species = $test_arr['animals'];
        print_r($find_species);

    }

    if(!empty($test_arr['birds']))
    {

        $find_species = $test_arr['birds'];
        print_r($find_species);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why you do `$test_arr[$search_filter[0]]=$temp_option_arr;` after `foreach` is over?

Comment: You clear `$temp_option_arr` in the first part of your code, so it will have nothing that concerns `animals`. by the time you exit the first loop. Maybe you should say what you are trying to achieve, because chances are that can be done in a 5-line code solution.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$test_arr[$search_filter[0]]=$temp_option_arr;
```

is out of the foreach scope, therefore it only sets the array for the birds and not for the animals, so you need to move it one line upper.

Also, you assign temp_option_arr to a value

```
array_push($temp_option_arr,$search_filter[1]);
```

then set it back to empty array without using it

```
$temp_option_arr=array();
```

You can remove the first one I guess

Answer (score 0):

You clear `$temp_option_arr` in the first part of your code, so it will have nothing that concerns *animals* by the time you exit the first loop.

But instead of using all these different arrays, just build an associative array keyed by the species (animals, birds, ...), and with as values the arrays of IDs (1, 2, 3, ... i.e., the parts after the `:`):

```
foreach($options_array_val as $options_val) {
    list($species, $id) = explode(":", $options_val);
    $option_arr[$species][] = $id;
}
```

After this loop the structure of `$option_arr` is this:

```
Array (
    "animals" => Array (1, 2, 3)
    "birds" => Array (1, 2)
)
```

I think you can do what you want with that. For instance to only get the animals:

```
$option_arr["animals"]
```

which is:

```
Array (1, 2, 3)
```